# Is ID3 Machine Learning Algorithm able to handle more than YES/NO classes?

Tags: machine-learning

I have spent the five days on this with little sleep and I am now at my wits end. In fact with the lack of sleep I now feel ill.

I have implemented ID3 with two classes e.g.`YES/NO` and now I have been tasked with a dataset that has 3x possible outcomes.

Example subset of data:

```
3.4,5.2,1.4,0.2,BarnOwl
2.3,4.5,1.3,0.3,BarnOwl
3.4,6,4.5,1.6,SnowyOwl
2.9,5.7,4.2,1.3,SnowyOwl
2.8,6.4,5.6,2.1,LongEaredOwl
3.2,6.4,5.3,2.3,LongEaredOwl
2.8,6.2,4.8,1.8,LongEaredOwl
2.3,5,3.3,1,SnowyOwl
```

I shuffle the data and take the first 100 entries as training data so an example breakdown:

```
{'SnowyOwl': 32, 'BarnOwl': 35, 'LongEaredOwl': 33}
```

and on calculating

`Entropy(32SO, 35BO, 33LO) =`
                               [image]

`= 1.58395`

I wrote my code and on checking the entropy function instead of getting a result in the range

`Entropy = [0..1]`

I get `1.58395`

The formula I have been given and works perfectly well with the `YES/NO` (sorry for quality)

[image]

To confirm my function is calculating the correct result albeit out side the expected range I used [http://www.wolframalpha.com/](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-%2832/100%29log2%2832/100%29-%2835/100%29log2%2835/100%29-%2833/100%29log2%2833/100%29)

Can any one please confirm this formula is correct?
And it so why is it outside the range I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The entropy of an `n`-valued discrete random variable lies in the range `[0, log2(n)]`. This means that for 3 outcomes the range will be `[0, \log2(3)] = [0, 1.58496250072]`. The answer is yes, your entropy formula is fine.

(To see this, note that the entropy achieves the maximum value when probability of all of the outcomes is the same, i.e., `1/n`. Then `-1/n\log2(1/n) - ... -1/n\log2(1/n) = n * 1/n * \log2(n) = log2(n)`. On the other hand, the entropy will take its minimum when one of the outcomes happens with probability 1 and all others happen with probability 0: `1*log2(1) - 0*log2(0) - ... - 0*log2(0) = 0`. This is why the range is `[0, log2(n)]`. I left out the proof that the entropy really takes its max and min at these two points. Note that I set `0*log2(0):=0`, since `log2(0)` doesn't exist. In practice one usually makes sure the summation goes over the terms `p*log2(p)` with `p>0`.)

Comment: Thank you so much Blaz. That makes perfect sense!

Comment: One other question if I could, in a YES/NO if there are zero NO's I return 0 as there is no entropy. But in my example if one of my classes is zero -(32/100)log2(32/100)-(68/100)log2(68/100)-(0/100)log2(0/100) will cause a crash. In fact I don't think I can successfully complete this which is unfortunate as KNN will solve this easily if I was allowed to use it.

Comment: Good answer. Note also that you can still normalize the entropy for more than two classes by using `log` with base N, where N is the number of classes. The maximum entropy will then be 1 for all equal probabilities (1 / N) and minimum entropy will still be 0 (when a single class has probability 1 and all others are 0).

Comment: @chris, will it crash because log2(0) is not defined? Perhaps you can check whether p=0; if so, just ignore that term as it doesn't contribute to the entropy. (Some time ago I implemented incremental decision tree learner [here](https://github.com/blazs/HoeffdingTree); consider looking into `hoeffding.cpp` for function that computes information gain; perhaps it will help you.)

Comment: That is exactly the cause of the crash. I took a short cut with YES/NO by checking if one was zero just return 0. Now I'll try implementing a simple check. It really helps to get some answers after all the reading I've put in. Thank you Blaz

Comment: @bogatron, I think it is better to normalize information gain --- I believe this is what chris is trying to compute in the end --- because it turns out that ``basic'' Information gain overestimates multivalued attributes in the sense that the more valued attribute you have the higher the information Gain. Normalizing information Gain eliminates this effect to some extent.

Comment: Well, *in the end*, normalization doesn't matter because he should end up with the same tree regardless. But with regard to @chris's expectation that the entropy be in the range [0..1], using logN does that. Of course, it also means that the information gain is limited to 1 as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right! In fact, since $log_N(p) = log_2(p)/log_2(N)$, changing base of log is equivalent to normalization I was talking about --- you normalize by dividing by the maximum information gain, which equals log_2(N) for N-class problem. :-)